# Download from table generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

How do I download data from this page using Visual Basic with Visual Studio 2010 (Windows form)?
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/spot-call-data.html
 I tried the following, but it only seems to give headers.
 If it can be downloaded using a batch file that would be great.  Otherwise Visual Basic is fine.
The values under the table are fetched using a Java script based on the trade date selected, so they are dynamic values and so can’t be seen when opened on the textpad.
 How can I get the values on the table?

This is what I tried.

```
Dim uriString As String = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/spot-call-data.html"
    ' Create a new WebClient instance.
    Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()

    Console.WriteLine(("Searching " + uriString + " ......."))

    myWebClient.DownloadFile(uriString, "C:\temp\searchresult.htm")
```

Comment: That's VB.NET, not C# :/

Comment: Sorry for the error.  Do you have a solution?

Comment: Is it possible to use the Web Inspector in Chrome to look at how the data is loaded.

Comment: If so, how?  I have installed the web inspector add on, but don't know what do to next.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on codeproject.com.  Here it is. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1205539/Download-from-page-which-uses-javascript-dynamical